# Cardinality of collection of all subsets whose cardinality is smaller than the original set

Tags: set-theory

Allow $[X]^{<\kappa}$ to be defined as the collection of all subsets of $X$ that have cardinality smaller than $\kappa$. If $\kappa > |X|$, then clearly $|[X]^{<\kappa}| = 2^{|X|}$. Also, it is easily verified that when $|X| = \aleph_0$ that $|[X]^{<\aleph_0}| = |X|$. My questions is the following. Let $\aleph_0 \leq |X| < 2^{\aleph_0}$. Is it apparent that $$|[X]^{<|X|}| = |X| $$

From the above, it is clear that the answer is yes if $X$ is countable. However, I'm unsure if (not assuming $\textsf{CH}$) that we could have this equality.

Edit: the motivation for the question is the following. We assume $\textsf{MA}$, and let $\aleph_0 \leq |X| < 2^{\aleph_0}$. Let $\mathbb{P} = (P, \leq)$ be a partially ordered set with members taken from $\mathcal{P}(X)$ such that $\mathbb{P}$ is c.c.c. and every singleton of $X$ is in $\mathbb{P}$. I want to construct a subset $Y \subset X$ such that $|Y| = |X|$ and $Y$ has the property that all finite subsets of $Y$ are members of $\mathcal{P}$. I want to construct a $\mathcal{D}$-generic filter using $\mathsf{MA}$ where $\mathcal{D}$ is a collection of dense sets indexed by the set $[X]^{<|X|}$. However, to invoke $\mathsf{MA}$, I need to verify that $|\mathcal{D}| < 2^{\aleph_0}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is flatly false, unless $|X|=\aleph_0$.

Suppose that $\aleph_0<|X|$, then $[X]^{<|X|}$ contains all the countable subsets of $X$, so its cardinality is *at least* $|X|^{\aleph_0}$, but that is *at least* as large as $2^{\aleph_0}$, and indeed equal to it under $\sf MA$.

In general we can't say lot about $[\kappa]^{<\kappa}$, only that its size is exactly $\kappa^{<\kappa}$, which can be very different between models of $\sf ZFC$. One thing though, is that if $\kappa=\lambda^+$, then $\kappa^{<\kappa}=\kappa^\lambda=2^\lambda$. Another is that if $\kappa$ is singular, then $\kappa<\kappa^{<\kappa}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for this quick response, as always. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Sure. Sorry it took so long!